# ConnectionNotFoundException j2me

Tags: java, exception, java-me, midp, midlet

I'have written the following code in j2me but it always throws ConnectionNotFoundException. I have disabled the windows firewall in case it blocks the netbeans network activity.

```
package networking;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.Connection;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

/**
 * @author Kanishk
 */
public class Midlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{

    private Command command;
    private Form form;
    private Display display;
    private String url = "http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt";
    private String local="http://127.0.0.1:8000";
    private HttpConnection c = null;
    private InputStream s = null;
    private Connection conn;

    public void startApp() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        form = new Form("Networking");
        command = new Command("Exit",Command.EXIT,0);
        form.addCommand(command);
        try {
            //conn = Connector.open(url);
            c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
            s = c.openInputStream();
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int readBytes = 0;

            while ((readBytes = s.read(byteArray)) > 0) {
                String temp = new String(byteArray, 0, readBytes);
                sb.append(temp);
                String inData = sb.toString();
                System.out.println(inData);
                form.append(inData);

                c.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            form.append("Connection failed.");
            System.out.println("here");
        }

//        if (s != null) {
//            form.append(inData);
//        } else if (s == null) {
//            form.append("Connection failed.");
//        }
        form.setCommandListener(this);
        display.setCurrent(form);
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    notifyDestroyed();
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d){
        if(c == command)
            destroyApp(true);
    }

}
```

The snapshot of output console is as follows:

```
Installing suite from: file:///C:/Users/Messi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/networking/dist/nbrun3458695790676134373/networking.jad
988830 - ERROR - AMS - 2 - Installation failed: com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteLockedException
com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteLockedException
    at com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteImpl.lockMIDletSuite(), bci=0
    at com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteStorage.getMIDletSuite(), bci=12
    at com.sun.midp.installer.Installer.checkPreviousVersion(), bci=60
    at com.sun.midp.installer.Installer.installStep2(), bci=10
    at com.sun.midp.installer.Installer.performInstall(), bci=132
    at com.sun.midp.installer.Installer.resumeInstallation(), bci=7
    at com.sun.midp.installer.MidpInstaller$StartAction.run(), bci=10
    at com.sun.j2me.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(), bci=12
    at com.sun.midp.installer.MidpInstaller$InstallThread.run(), bci=9
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:743)
javacall_lifecycle_state_changed() lifecycle: event is JAVACALL_LIFECYCLE_MIDLET_SHUTDOWN status is JAVACALL_OK
javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: error 10061 in socket::open
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open0(), bci=0
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.connect(), bci=184
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open(), bci=216
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.openPrim(), bci=4
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.createConnection(), bci=41
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.connect(), bci=41
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.streamConnect(), bci=164
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.startRequest(), bci=7
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=33
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=3
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.getResponseCode(), bci=5
 - networking.Main.run(Main.java:68)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:743)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: In networking.jad, take a look at MIDlet-Jar-URL. Does it start with http?

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota No, it shows: MIDlet-Jar-URL: networking.jar

Comment: Did you open networking/dist/nbrun3458695790676134373/networking.jad ?

Comment: Yes. But it didnt start with http.